# MySql Important Linux System Configuration

Tags: mysql, performance, linux, configuration, best-practices

Last month I'm trying to find a "formula" for optimal Linux system configuration for MySql installation. But I didn't find anything related in those fields:

Should I disable swapping ?
Increase file descriptors
Insure sufficient threads
other common linux based system configurations

What are `nofile` and `nproc` values you are setting up for production mysql installations?
Any good reads in that field?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/

Comment: @GerardH.Pille , thanks , I'm familiar with that part of documentation , I have not seen the answers for my questions there though.

Answer (score 1):

The default installation is fine for typical usage.

If you have extremely heavy usage, then explain what kind of app you have and how much RAM and data.

Swapping is bad for performance, but not having swap space when needed is worse.  Still, generally a dedicated server with a default configuration is not likely to hit such.

A "busy system" would be hundreds of queries per second or saturation of either CPU or I/O.

If the machine will have both the app and MySQL, then take into consideration how big the footprint for the app is.

Comment: Hi Rick , thank you for your answer (thats cool since I was reading your blog posts the other day)

I have a MySql of 1 master and 6 read replicas , all around 22GB ram right now.
The usage is kind of heavy and yea its more than hundreds of queries per seconds sometime.
I have took care of mysql configurations long time ago, but I always wondered about linux system configurations since never seen that they being mentioned somewhere, in databases like elasticsearch they are must and always being mentioned.

Comment: around 150GB of Data. I didn't get the answer about swapping? Should I disable it ? I mean like
`On Linux systems, you can disable swap temporarily by running: sudo swapoff -a. To disable it permanently, you will need to edit the /etc/fstab file and comment out any lines that contain the word swap.`

Comment: @MarkDavydov - No, don't disable swapping.  Configure things so that it is mostly avoided.  Sometimes I see a `my.cnf` with settings so large that they are destined to swap.